# How to handle changing SQL Server database column type with EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a situation where we have created an API (.NET Core C#) that can be deployed on several sites that can have different versions of SQL Server database (3rd party database, we have no way to change them). The problem is that while the table structure remains the same, the column types might change. Lets say for example that there is a field in a table in the database of type `TINYINT` on site 1 and on site 2 the database is updated and the new type for the same field is now `INT`. We use EF Core 2.2, database first approach to handle the database and the problem is that when we update the API to handle the new `INT` type for site 2, the same API on site 1 throws and error about being unable to convert byte to int32. We can't keep different versions of the API for different sites.

My question is: is it possible to handle this in EF Core in some way? In 2.2? Or in any of the newer version?

I know I could create a procedure in the database to get the data and make sure it always returns the same type (we are not writing to the database, only reading), but this feels like an ugly solution, not to mention a huge undertaking to cover all the tables we need.

Maybe some extension on the EF models? Though I have no idea if that is possible and if it is, how to go about doing it.

Comment: Of course you can run plain ADO.Net code to first sniff out the database and then create the EF model in which some properties are mapped/not mapped conditionally, or value converters switched on/off. But I think this situation should be avoided at all cost. It would be perfectly normal to demand a specific database schema if people want to use your API. That should be a take it or leave it condition.

Comment: Thank you Gert for the suggestion, but as you say it should be avoided and thus we ended up with the "take it or leave it"

Answer (score -2):

For some unknown reason no, EF Core doesn't include generic functionality to handle your incredibly specific requirement.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? It's quite a bold statement that something can't be done. It requires solid justification.

Comment: As stated please provide soures for your claim to help others understand why and how they can solve their issue.